# PHP - single dimension array to a multidimensional

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I'm using jquery to send a serialized single dimensional array to my php script.

Upon arriving at the server: The array should be transformed into a multidimensional array where every 2 values in the original array are a new row.

```
   $oldarray
```

looks like `(value1, value2, value3, value4)`

```
  $newarray =array();
```

Should look like

```
(   Value1, Value2
    Value3, Value4  )
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the purpose of having them on new lines? That won't change how the data is handled in php. To make it a multidimensional array you would have to push each array into another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array_chunk](https://www.php.net/array-chunk) for this:

```
 $newarray = array_chunk($oldarray, 2);
```

The first example on the linked doc page shows this exact use case.